# IE7 Dropdown Menu Make li Fill Remaining Space

Tags: html, css, menu, drop-down-menu

I have created a dropdown menu using CSS and JavaScript and I'm having an issue making the sub-menus appear correctly on IE7.  When you hover on an anchor tag the background changes to blue.  The problem is that in IE7 the background only changes for the length of the text rather than filling the width of the ul.  So, if you have one item that has a long name, the rest display incorrectly as shown by the picture below.

[image: IE7 issue]

You can see the problem on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/atg3W/1/).  Just make sure you open it in IE7 or use IE9 in compatibility mode.

I have tried a bunch of things like setting the width to 100% and the display to block but haven't been able to get it to work.  Has anyone solved this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `width: 89%` on hover ? `#mainmenu li a:hover { width: 89%; background: #008de2;}` , try it :). I don't have IE-7 to test it myself. Just tested on Firefox.

Comment: No that didn't work either.  What is your logic?

Comment: Speaking frankly, used Firebug and gave random % to test how it is doing. I gave 100% at first and highlighting part is overflown on hovering. For 89% it was perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's see what do you have:

```
<li><a href="#">Content</a></li>
```

so you can see that the problem is that the `hover` is being applied to the `<a>` and because it's not wide enough it does not work correctly.

Why don't you `hover` the `<li>` instead then?

changing from

```
#mainmenu li a:hover { background: #008de2; }
```

to

```
#mainmenu li:hover { background: #008de2; }
```

**P.S.** I'm using IE9, so I can't test it properly :-/

Comment: using Developer Tools, can you see why does the hover only works in the `<a>` after you changed the CSS to hover the hole `<li>`?

Comment: I appologize. That does work. I just needed to change the css for the submenu (#mainmenu li ul li:hover not @mainmenu li:hover).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `display:block` on those anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

You may find your solution [here (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Larry/YLH8R/10/).

I made a few changes to `#mainmenu li ul li`, as well as adding `#mainmenu li ul li:hover { background: #008de2;}`. Seems fine on my IE7, IE9 (don't have IE8 to test), Safari, Firefox, Opera, and Chrome :)